# Is it feasible to download win10 iso from a win10 machine?

Tags: windows-10, iso-image

I accessed the url https://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/software-download/windows10ISO from my mac and got this page

[image]

Clicking the button pointed out by the red arrow starts downloading the iso file.

However, when I accessed the same url from my win10 machine, I got anther page

[image]

where I can only download a burn-iso-to-usb tool.

How do I download win10 iso from a win10 machine?

Comment: You can download Windows 10 from the link you posted and either run Setup from that ISO or use Rufus to make a bootable USB key.

Comment: Changing the user agent is the solution to your problem.